# Java several classes beginner struggle

Tags: java

so I am currently taking an online coding class. and it has us make two different codes. one called SpaService. and one called CreateSpaService.
From my understanding, these are supposed to work together, to call variable (etc.) but it is not working and I am being hit with syntax errors saying that variables are not declared, but I declared them in the other code.

Am I supposed to put them in the same doc or something? I tried that and it still wouldn't work. Is there some way I have to link the two codes so they work together?
Here are the two codes.
also, do you see any syntax errors?
Thank you so much

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreateSpaServices
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   
   
   SpaService firstService = new SpaService();
   SpaService secondService = new SpaService();
   
  firstService = getData(firstService);
  secondService = getData(secondService);

   System.out.println("First service details:");
   System.out.println(firstService.getServiceDescription() + " $" + firstService.getPrice());
   
   System.out.println("Second service details:");
   System.out.println(secondService.getServiceDescrption() + " $" + secondService.getPrice());
    
 }
 public static SpaService getData(SpaService service)
 {
   String service;
   double price;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("Enter service >> ");
   service = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Enter price >> ");
   price = keyboard.nextDouble();
   keyboard.nextLine();
   service.setServiceDescription(Service);
   service.setPrice(price);
   return service;
 }
}





//here is other code, im not sure if where I put this, or if I keep it in its own document or in this doc.

public class SpaService
{
 private String serviceDescription;
  private double price;
  
  public SpaService()
  {
    serviceDescription = "XXX";
    price = 0;
  }
  public void setServiceDescription(String service)
  {
    serviceDescription = service;
  }
  public void setPrice(double servicePrice)
  {
    price = servicePrice;
  }
  public String getServiceDescription;
  {
return serviceDescription;
}
public double getPrice()
{
  return price;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make as small of an example as you can that exhibits the problem, and then show the *complete, exact* error that results.

Comment: If you add error message or stack trace, then people can find what's wrong easier.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the two classes in respective files in the same folder location:

```
SpaService.java
CreateSpaServices.java
```

Comment: That's the recommended way in Java. Every class in its own file. Also best practice is to modularize related files in subfolders and use package statements at the top of the files. For a starter project have an App.java in the root-directory which contains the class "App". App has a "static main()". Create a subfolder e.g. "SpaModule", that contains the file SpaService.java wherein the first statement should be "package SpaModule;". In App.java then insert "import SpaModule.SpaService;". The pathes of packages can of course contain more subfolders than 1.

Comment: But what if they already are in the same folder, and if I try any of that I get tons fo errors

Comment: the error tracking tells you what the errors are. For example, I noticed your getData method passes a SpaService object as a parameter (service) and then you try to declare a String variable of the same name in the method. It's generally considered bad form in StackOverflow to request a general "fix my code" question, and it's bad form for a respondent to simply paste in working code. I got the program to work, I think I changed 3 or 4 things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of IDE or using command prompt to manually compile and execute? IDE make things very simple but they  take away some finer learning details for beginners.

Anyway a text file can have one Public class and any number of non-public class. As your both classes are public it should be in different file. Classes are linked to each other via import statement , which must be first line in java class if any.

You should get some compile issues also as I can see this method
public static SpaService getData(SpaService service)
As you are returning service variable which is of type String, but your method signature is expecting SpaService

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are useful for understanding the class structure, but you have an issue with your code issue that is likely causing the majority of your problem.

1. In the `getData` method you have two items named `service`, the `SpaService service` and `String service;`, you need to change one of them.
2. This line is not valid `service.setServiceDescription(Service);`, you can't refer to `Service` with a capital `S`, you need to reference to a valid string.

Here is an example that takes the above into account:

```
 public static SpaService getData(SpaService service)
 {
   //Create a scanner
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   //Get scanner input
   System.out.print("Enter service >> ");
   String description = keyboard.nextLine();

   //Add input to SpaService object
   service.setServiceDescription(description);

   //Get scanner input
   System.out.print("Enter price >> ");
   double price = keyboard.nextDouble();

   //Add input to SpaService object
   service.setPrice(price);

   //Return SpaService object
   return service;
 }
```

For better help please edit your question to include the full error.